# How to do these permission granting commands in Windows Explorer?

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5, file-permissions, windows-security

In this [tutorial](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/321/configure-ftp-with-iis-7-manager-authentication/), I found the following commands.

```
ICACLS "%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" /Grant "Network Service":R /T
ICACLS "%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config" /Grant "Network Service":R
ICACLS "%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config" /Grant "Network Service":R
```

1. How to do these using Windows Explorer?
2. What does the `/T` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICACLS is a command line tool. You need to use the comand line.

/T performs the operation on all specified files in the current directory and its subdirectories. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc753525(v=WS.10).aspx